# Algorithm to auto-pick 11 players in a fantasy football lineup where the total price is near N

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of 500 floats.

I want to pick 11 numbers out of the list which when added together sum up to N and N is within a range X <= N <= Y

It's basically for a fantasy football game where we autopick 11 players in the persons lineup.

The total cost should be somewhere within a range rather than random.

One solution might be to continuously randomly pick 11 players until I get a total that fits within the range but i'm wondering if there is a more elegant approach?

Comment: Dynamic Programming :) Its a modified version of knapsack problem.

Comment: Also a modified version of the subset sum problem. Not surprising, given both are NP-complete.

Comment: You need just one pick? And it has to give a fair chance to all players?

Comment: Thanks thefourtheye, didn't even know what to google for!

Comment: You do not have to pick players at random. Selecting random players will cause collisions that will slow down finding a solution. Instead of that, you can systematically loop through different combinations, hoping to fall on a solution soon enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the commenters pointed out, this is an NP-hard problem.  However, if your data isn't too bad, the following should work pretty well:

```
picks[] := K numbers chosen at random from the population
While sum(picks) is not in the allowable range
  if sum(picks) < MinRange
    select an element p from picks at random
    let subpop := elements in population which are larger than p
    replace p with a random element from subpop
  if sum(picks) > MaxRange
    select an element p from picks at random
    let subpop := elements in population which are smaller than p
    replace p with a random element from subpop
```

This is pretty easy to code up, it will return a relatively random selection that satisfies the constraints, and it shouldn't take too long unless you really have a hard instance of the problem, in which case it's going to be very hard to find a solution using any algorithm.

If you want to speed up the algorithm, then you can choose the element `p` to be the smallest/largest element from `picks` each time through.  This should make the algorithm go faster, but it will also result in a less "random" selection of picks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not best approach, but it might work:

```
import random

data  # list of 500 floats
n = 11 # numbers to pick
bottom_limit = X
top_limit = Y
max_tries = 100

data_min = min(data)
data_max = max(data)

i = 0
while i < max_tries:
    i += 1
    picked = []

    for j in xrange(n-1):  # pick random except the last one
        picked.append(random.choice(data))
    s = sum(picked)

    if s + data_min < top_limit and s + data_max > bottom_limit:
        # Ok, we know we can find proper values, let's do it
        filtered = []
        for value in data:
            if value + s > bottom_limit and value + s < top_limit:
                filtered.append()

        picked.append(random.choice(filtered))
        break  # Success
else:
    print 'Unable to pick, sorry'
```

Success rate is highly relative to the data and limits values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What are X and Y? Can you approximate them and players' scores with integers?
If so, than you can use dynamic programming like for 
[knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

But there are several problems.

1. This algorithm needs O(Y) memory and O(M + Y) time, where M is total number of players.
2. If you want to find all allowable teams and then choose random one, then you'll have a problem, that there are possibly exponential amount of such teams.

So for practical approach my vote is for mrip's suggestion.